# How to make flavoured salt for potato chips

Tags: chicken, flavor, chips

A chips shop offers potato chips (french fries, in the US) in different flavour like chicken, chicken roast, bar b q, et cetera. I saw they make simple potato chips and then add a salt type stuff to it which gives flavour to the chips.

How can I to make flavoured salt like that?

Comment: You are referring to hot potato chips, AKA French fries?

Comment: The US readers are assuming from the title that you're talking about the thin, fried, crispy snack food that comes in bags.  Can you edit your title?  You might get more accurate suggestions.  :-)

Comment: I don't think we need to wait for the OP to edit here - US chips shops (crisps, in the UK) don't commonly exist, so chips shop clearly means UK chips, US french fries.

Answer (score 4):

To make seasoned salt, just put salt and dry spices into a spice grinder.

A lot of times they have an additive that makes this salt/powder stick to chips.  Also if you are frying them salt and seasoning will stick to them for a few moments after they come out of the fryer.

Comment: I think the question is how to make flavored salt, not how to get it to stick.

Comment: @derobert , yes you are right i am asking about how to make that salt type stuff

Comment: put salt and spices into a spice grinder...  blammo  salty stuff.

Comment: It's best to edit your answer, rather than leave the core of what the OP wanted hidden in a comment. I've gone ahead and done that.